# Android: uploading user images to server (Volley/Blob)

Tags: android, sqlite, blob, android-volley

I want to perform a simple action, to upload user images from the app to online server to store them and to have them available for future uses.

For that purpose, I will use [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) library.

Basically I would convert the image into [Base64](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) format, send it to server, and store it.

My question, however, is that I have read answers to other questions here at stackoverflow about [BLOB](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/Blob.html) for storing data into database. Could anyone explain if BLOB is needed in this case or if am I mixing concepts here?.

**INFO**: My initial idea is to **store the images in another folder** in the server, and maybe the name and the path to the images in the database...but not the image in the database.

Comment: That depends on if you want your images to be saved in the database, or as files outside the database. If the files are outside the database, you can then place them in a folder the webserver can reach, and set the URL as the user's `image` in the database. This way, your database wouldn't have to send large files, your webserver does.

Comment: @zed thanks I will clarify that info in my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making your own  external **Folder** for saving images would be better than saving the `Images` in the `database` , because when you save the `images` as **BLOB** in the database some of the problems you face in database transfer is that, the `database` becomes to huge to transfer , but when you create a **folder** aside and you just call the names of the images in the Database , that is much more better.  and `Volley` is also good in this.

If you need like a code sample i can post it

Thanks .

Comment: thanks for the answer, and no need code sample thanks, just needed to be sure if Volley was the good solution as you clarified.